# VBA - Assigning Date Format to Column and Apply Date Filter

Tags: vba, excel

I have the two Macro's which filters a worksheet column by date and then delete's the irrelevant columns.

However, it is very buggy and I need some help to correct that please.

This is what is supposed to happen with the first Macro:

1) **Format column B from row 2 down to the last row in date format dd-mm-yyyy** - Currently this does not happen, and at some point it was applying the format to the ENTIRE column B, including the empty cells after the data

2) **Apply the filter on column B (date) to display all records except the day prior to the current day** - It's half correct, because it's not including the current day in the filter. When I run the "delete" Macro, the cells that are displayed are the current day and the previous day, I should only see the previous day.

```
Sub DateFilter()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Current_Date As Date

On Error Resume Next

Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet")

LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With ws1

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Cells

        Current_Date = CDate(c)
        c.Value = Current_Date

    Next c

End With

x = CLng(Date)
ws1.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<" & x, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & x - 1

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like 4 separate questions, or at least more than one? I would keep each post to a single question. In your first one, 'LastRow` is defined in terms of column A - perhaps that is the issue. Why are not just applying a format?

Comment: @SJR my apologies, I have updated the post and removed the second part of the question. I will try not do so again in the future. :)

Comment: @SJR with regards to your second question, some of the fields in column B are mm-dd-yyyy and some are yyyy-mm-dd, but I want them all to be dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: OK, thanks. Please see @Zac's answer, though that may need some revision in light of this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SJR suggested, you have too many questions in one post so I will only look at the first macro. To get a resolution for your second macro, please start a new thread

Below code should achieve your requirements for first macro with some comments to help you understand the code

```
Sub DateFilter()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet")

    ' On Error Resume Next      VERY very bad idea as this will hide all issues in the code!

    With oWS

        ' Set the range format to specified date format. This will automatically update
        ' the values in the cells to a date.. no need to copy and paste them
        .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"

        ' Set the autofilter to display all dates other than yesterdays
        .Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(DateAdd("d", -1, Date)), Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=">" & CLng(DateAdd("d", -1, Date))

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this code and your comments, I appreciate it. The code is working except there is one issue, I mentioned in a reply to SJR above, some of the fields in column B are mm-dd-yyyy and some are yyyy-mm-dd, but I want them all to be dd-mm-yyyy. After your filter is applied, there are still fields in the yyyy-mm-dd format showing.

Comment: Hmmm, bizarre, it works for me. Can you provide a sample of your sheet in your question?

Comment: I see that there are some fields that show as general number only as well. This is also why I needed to apply the date format. I will upload a sample shortly.

Comment: I dont know what to say @Zac, I just tried it now again and it worked 100%. So I suppose this has been solved! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: No problems, glad it helped

Comment: I tried the macro on a different sheet and the cells that have yyyy-mm-dd are not changed to dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Did you remember to change the name of the sheet in the sub?

Comment: Yes @Zac, I did. There's two dates I can immediately see that do not change in my data - 2016-10-11 (line 42) and 2017-05-26 (line 94). What happens is that the filter "hides" these lines.

Comment: Format is changed before filter is applied.. confused. As per before, if you can provide a sample of your sheet, I can then test with your data

Comment: I know this is going to sound rather dumb, but I cant seem to figure out how to upload an attachment to my question.. I have the sample book ready for you but I cant find the upload button...

Comment: That's definitely not dumb because I don't know the answer to that either as I haven't asked a question here in soo long (well I did ask a question the other day but never had to upload files). Might be worth asking SJR maybe? :)

Comment: So a quick Google search revealed that you cannot directly upload a file. You need to upload it to a cloud service and then provide the link to the file.. Ill do that quickly.

Comment: Apologies im only replying now. I managed to get the code working by combining your code and the code from my actual post. I used the For Each loop from my code inside your with block and removed your first line of code inside the with block and it does the trick :)